# Resolve circular dependency in Swift

Tags: swift

Let's say I have 2 classes that both need each other.

```
class LoginInteractor {

     let userInteractor: UserInteractor

     init(userInteractor: UserInteractor) {
        self.userInteractor = userInteractor
     }

}

class  UserInteractor {
    let loginInteractor: LoginInteractor

    init(loginInteractor: LoginInteractor) {
        self.loginInteractor = loginInteractor
     }
}
```

If I try this ( let loginInteractor = LoginInteractor() ) I would get a circular dependency. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: You need each class to create the other. That can't work. You need to make  it so at least one of the two can be created without the initial need of the other.

Comment: Adding to @rmaddy's comment, one way to do this would be to make one of the properties optional, though that would need a semantics where nil was a meaningful value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have two classes where the initializer of both requires a reference to the other. It's simply not possible.

You need to change at least one of the classes to have an initializer that does not need the other.

Then you also have a problem of both having a strong reference to the other. This will cause a reference cycle (a form of memory leak). So in addition to changing one of the initializers, you should make one of the references weak.

So in the end, you need to make this much like you would any other parent-child class reference.

Without knowing more, I would suggest updating `UserInteractor` to not require the `LoginInteractor`. You might have a user that does several things, login being just one possible case.

```
class UserInteractor {
    weak var loginInteractor: LoginInteractor?

    init() {
    }
}

class LoginInteractor {
     let userInteractor: UserInteractor {
         didSet {
             userInterator.loginInteractor = self
         }
     }

     init(userInteractor: UserInteractor) {
        self.userInteractor = userInteractor
     }
}
```

With this setup you can create an instance of `UserInteractor`. You can then create an instance of `LoginInteractor` using your instance of `UserInteractor`.

```
let userInteractor = UserInteractor()
let loginIteractor = LoginInteractor(userInteractor: userInteractor)
```

Comment: So imagine this scenario: You have a loginInteractor which given an user and a password makes a request, if its ok save this user using UserInteractor.saveLoggedUser. Now imagine everytime the apps its initiated, if the user is already loggedin, you perform a UserInteractor.updateProfile(), but the session sometimes its expired, so you get an error, and you need to do a LoginInteractor.login(storedCredentails) inside the UserInteractor, and you want to do tests on in mocking the loginInteractor to see if its really called after an error updating the profile

Comment: If the session is expired, then you should invalidate/delete your `UserInteractor`, which would force the user to login, using the `LogintInteractor`. And after a successful login, you'd then create a new `UserInteractor` with the necessary information. So the best way to go about this would be to have the 2 classes not related at all